# проблема ts2322. Не могу передать объект classes в чекбокс

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Переписываю проект с jsx на tsx и после смены на tsx появилась ошибка у чекбокса от ui kit mui для classes.

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Partial<CheckboxClasses> | undefined'.
  Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<CheckboxClasses>'.ts(2322)
Checkbox.d.ts(26, 3): The expected type comes from property 'classes' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CheckboxProps'
```

По порядку.
1.Есть интерфейс с описанием данных и реализуемыми ими типами[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2.При передаче в чекбокс получаю такую ошибку и не могу понять как мне её решить :([image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. также [передаю сам чекбокс на гуглдиске](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KcSd2pCIV5oRvMQOx-Af54APN3zDV5We?usp=sharing) (напоминаю, что он не самописный, а с библиотеки [mui](https://mui.com/)

Comment: До перехода на tsx всё работало и при этом стили работали. Сейчас же сам компонент функционирует если я поставлю ts-ignore перед строкой с ошибкой, но стили слетели

Comment: `checkbox?: Partial<CheckboxClasses>`, а не `string`

Comment: @EzioMercer , спасибо, вроде помогло, но пока не уверен т.к. всплыла следующая ошибка)

Comment: Дополните этот вопрос или можете удалить этот и открыть новый

Comment: @EzioMercer , создал. Если понимаете в чём беда, то буду очень благодарен https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1435733/uncaught-typeerror-cant-access-property-container-classes-is-undefined . Также можете написать ваш ответ в ответы отмечу как правильный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо сменить тип для `checkbox` в `AccordionProps.classes`. А именно надо поменять `string` на `Partial<CheckboxClasses>`