# Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "container", classes is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Всем привет и заранее спасибо за помощь :)
Предисловие: перевожу проект на TS и возникают некоторые ошибки...к сожалению я пока слаб в тс, а тем более в коллаборации с реактом((
По порядку:
1.Импортирую css
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Создал интерфейс где описываю реализацию типов данных:(тут же и лежит classes, иначе оно ругается)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3.Передаём всё это в пропсы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4.Получаем ошибку доступа к классам

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "container", classes is undefined
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем-то на этом всё :\ Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную проблему. Как я понял импортируемые стили перебились одноимённым описанием в компоненте и я попал в тупик

UPD:
При выводе classes в console.log вывод undefined[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Когда небыло tsx и описания classes в interface все классы работали

Comment: Перед `return`-ом выведите в коносль `classes` и покажите добавив в вопрос скриншот того что там находится. Там скорее всего будет `undefined`, что значит, что вы не передаёте в компоненту `Accordion` переменную `classes`

Comment: @EzioMercer , дополнил. Там undefined

Comment: @EzioMercer , понял, прочёл. Подскажите, а как быть в случае, что необходимо описать classes в интерфейсе и передать как css в компонент?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Вам просто надо передать этот `classes`, там где вы его импортируете в компоненту `Accordion`